# How to handle CORS error, while fetching firebase realtime database API in vue project?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, cors

I am using vue-2.And want to do shallow query for firebase realtime database by fetching API.But  While running on development server ,it shows CORS blocked. What should I do?
PS: I am also using vuefire

```
created(){
    var apiUrl = 'https://console.firebase.google.com/u/4/project/enajori-45094/database/enajori-45094/data/Admin/Data%20Collection/Paying%20Guest';
    fetch(apiUrl).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

[Cors error i am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B90p.png)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, do not show pictures of code and text. Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase `REST-Api` only reacts to `HTTPS-Requests`. If your localhost doesen't have SSL enabled your requests will fail no matter what your try. The `URI` also need to end with the the table's name like `something.json`

And you realy should use the Firebase SDK - it's the smoother way.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew about the .json part

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely unclear to me why you would want to use a URL to the **Firebase console** to access the database.  Console URLs are for human consumption, not for programs.

You should use the provided javascript SDK to access data.  It will work around CORS issues for you automatically, and give you a much cleaner way to read and write data.  If you can't use the SDK, you can always try the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database).  Just don't depend on those console URLs at all.

Comment: Thank you  for answering. You are always the one to the rescue.  I wanted it for doing a shallow query anyway I solved the issue. There was a problem with the url and also mistakenly didn't append .json to end of url